# How to render data on dataTable on Post returned data?

Tags: datatable, datatables

I posted data to server and i want to use the return data as the data of my datatable

```
var table = $(tbl_id).DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "type": "POST",
            "url": data_url + '/count_plantilla',
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "data": {
                "plantilla_name": plantilla_name
            }

        }
```

Comment: If your data is array of arrays/objects where each parent array record corresponds to table row and child array/object entry corresponds to table column, you simply need to add `ajax: {..., dataSrc: ''}` and use `columns/columnDefs` option to map your source array/object onto your table columns.

Comment: can you show some reference sir?

Comment: Append sample of your data returned in response to POST.